# Number of elements in string doesn't match number of bind variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
// prepare and bind
```

Hi,

I receive the following error while trying to execute my query through prepared statements:

```
Number of elements in string doesn't match number of bind variables
```

Below code:

```
$track = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO resources_record (name,email,stage,format,topic,max_cost,mentor,total_cost,duration)
              VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?')");
    $track->bind_param($fullName, $email, $stage, $format, $topic, $cost, $mentor, $price, $duration);

    // Execute
    $track->execute();

    $track->close();
```

Comment: Don't put quotes around the placeholders in your prepared statements

Comment: The first argument to `bind_param()` should be a string identifying the datatypes of the subsequent arguments - [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two obvious faults here:

- Don't put quotes around the placeholders in your prepared statements
- The first argument to `bind_param()` should be a string identifying the datatypes of the subsequent arguments - [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

---

```
$track = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO resources_record (name,email,stage,format,topic,max_cost,mentor,total_cost,duration)
          VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$track->bind_param('sssssssss', $fullName, $email, $stage, $format, $topic, $cost, $mentor, $price, $duration);
```

A string comprising 9 `s`, because you have 9 arguments, and all are string (`s`) values